# index time document boost not taken into account

Tags: solr

I try to increase document score via index time boosting.

I post following json to solr server:

```
{ 
"add": {
 "boost":150,
  "doc": {
        "id":"doc12345",
        "fieldToCheckUpdateExecuted":"some value"
 }
},
"commit":{}
}
```

but when I query solr for `doc12345`, I get `score=1`

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"id:doc12345",
      "indent":"true",
      "fl":"id, score, fieldToCheckUpdateExecuted",
      "sort":"score asc",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"doc12345",
        "fieldToCheckUpdateExecuted":"some value",
        "score":1.0}]
  }}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the definition of the `id` field?

Comment: @fiskfisk, `<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />`

Comment: Are you using version 1.5 for the schema? (see the first tag of the schema)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with schema.xml version 1.5, the native types (string, int, float, boolean, etc.) has `omitNorms` enabled by default. norms are required for index time boosting for a field, so if `omitNorms` is enabled, index time boosting will not work for that field (and document boosting is the same boost applied to all fields).

Setting `omitNorms=false` for the id field and reindexing should show another score.

The currently [recommended way of doing boosts](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_change_the_score_of_a_document_based_on_the_.2Avalue.2A_of_a_field_.28say.2C_.22popularity.22.29) is to employ a FunctionQuery and base it on the value of a field in your document for the boost (`{!boost b=field}`).

Comment: Setting `omitNorms` to false really helped. But I'd like to increase document score despite the way it was found (if document is included in search result its score should be increased). Is it possible to do?

Comment: I can not modify query sent to solr. But I need to tweak score of some documents to check that documents are correctly ordered (there are several sort fields).

Comment: I did not understand your issue .. if the document is included in the search result, it is included because of its score (.. meaning that it matches). What use case are you trying to solve? Having norms allows index time boosting which sounds like what you want .. another option is the [QueryElevationComponent](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent) to manually place documents at the top for certain queries